# Database Design: Different objects from one table? (No inheritance)

Tags: database, object

I have a list of fields that I concatenate, for instance : field1 + ';' + field2.
Here is my solution on how to store these concatenations (v1):

```
FieldID | Position  | Prefix  | ConcatenationID

15      |0          |NULL     | 30

28      |1          |;        | 30
```

But I feel this solution is not that elegant. I think about replacing it with this table (V2):

```
FieldID | Position  | Separator       | ConcatenationID     | IsSeparator

15      |0          |NULL             |30                   | False

NULL    |1          |;                |30                   | True

28      |2          |NULL             |30                   | False
```

-V1 has the advantage of storing only one object (Field) but fails to represent the separator in a clear way.

-V2 has the advantage of representing the separator in a clear way but stores multiple objects (Field & Char/String). Also : I hate NULL Columns.

What do you guys of both versions?

Thanks in advance for your eventual answers.

Comment: I'm completely stumped -- what are the entities that you are actually trying to represent, and what attributes do they have?

Comment: J, it really depends on which solution I choose but both have only to tables 'Field' & 'Concatenation'

Answer (score 0):

```
Value|Position (CPK) |ConcatenationID (CPK)
15   |0              |30
;    |1              |30
28   |2              |30
;    |3              |30
15   |0              |40
;    |1              |40
4    |2              |40
;    |3              |40
```

I don't know what is the schematic meaning of field and a separator in your business situation but i have simply derived to the following.

```
select value
from table
where concatenationId = 30 
order by position;
```

But if you need to differentiate between a field and a separator.

```
Value|TypeId|Position (CPK)|ConcatenationID (CPK)
15   |0     |0             |30
;    |1     |1             |30
28   |0     |2             |30
;    |1     |3             |30
15   |0     |0             |40
;    |1     |1             |40
4    |0     |2             |40
;    |1     |3             |40
```

Type Table:

```
TypeId|Type
0     |Field
1     |Separator
```

SQL:

```
select value, type
from table
left join type
using (typeId)
where concatenationId = 30 
order by position;
```

Comment: Thanks Chin for formatting my post. As for your suggestion: it drops the FK to the table 'Field' which I want to keep.